# How to handle relations one-to-many in SwiftData without getting `unknown related type`

Tags: swift, swift-data, swift-data-relationship

I am struggling with probably simple issue but at the moment I cannot see why it appears. So in SwiftData I want to create an object and later I wish to build related object and assign it. Lets lets jump into code, models look like following:

```
@Model
class Person {
     var name: String
     var age: Int
     var cars: [CarModel]?
}

@Model
class CarModel {
     var name: String
     var owner: Person?
}
```

With such construction I create Car first, then I want to assign a person to it. Person object is newly created, not yet stored in DB. When assigning Person to Car I get the following error `Unknown related type`:

```
var car = CarModel()
var owner = Person()
car.owner = owner
```

Do you have any clues? Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Insert at least one of the objects into your model context before creating the relationship to start with and see if that solves the issue

Comment: how about in your `Person` using `var cars: [CarModel]?`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine nice catch. I didn’t see that typo